# What are some resources for learning Lambda Calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

So the Wikipedia entry on [Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) was interesting but I've finished it.  I wish to dive a little deeper and get a better understanding of Lambda Calculus.

Can anyone recommend what they consider to be the best book or primer to Lambda Calculus?

Comment: See the math.sx question [Learning Lambda Calculus](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967/learning-lambda-calculus/1059#1059)

Comment: I voted to reopen as, despite being off-topic from some viewpoints , the subject is really central to programming and we should hear other opinions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are done with the Wikipedia entry, follow its link to the online [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), do the assignments, or read [the book](http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf).

Comment: +1 This is a classic resource. It was the coursebook for my uni's first programming course.

Comment: ditto. although it's more about practicalness, not about the formal-ness of lambda calculus itself.

Comment: +1 Reading now...instead of 6-7 years ago... Rocks a developer's/coder's/programmer's world.

Comment: Play around in DrRacket for a while.

Comment: @gimel How does SICP help in learning lambda calculus.

Comment: @batman - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750421/what-type-of-lambda-calculus-would-lisp-loosely-be-an-example-of (Lisp corresponds to an untyped, call-by-value lambda calculus extended with constants.)

Comment: sicp does not help learning lambda calculus, but help to practice it practically.

Comment: SICP does not help learning Lambda Calculus. It is NOT a book on Lambda Calculus, but on programming.

Answer (score 16):

Well, there's always [An Introduction to Lambda Calculus](http://web.archive.org/web/20170809103332if_/http://gpl.internetconnection.net/mirror-lambda-calculus.pdf). I've tried reading it a few times, but always got stuck. I have a nagging feeling that I already know most of this stuff and would probably have an easier time understanding it if it was presented in terms of Lisp/Scheme rather than math. You might have better luck, though :)

Answer (score 12):

I found "[An introduction to Lambda Calculi for Computer Scientists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0954300653)" by Chris Hankin to be pretty good, but I only really used it for one class - not used it in the real world :)

[image]

Comment: Best of the books I've tried

Comment: @ThomasAhle what other books have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

I think the reference on the subject of lambda-calculus itself still is [Barendregt's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444875085).

[image]

Beyond that it pretty much depends on what "part" of lambda-calculus you are interested in : typing ? proof theory ? term rewriting ? functional programming ?

Each of these is a field in itself, and I don't know of any book that covers it all.

Comment: correct, but it is for very advanced programmers, not for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

Try writing a lambda calculus interpetter, ideally in a functional language using the build in syntax of the language rather than via a parser.  This is surprisingly easy and a good way to improve your feel for it.

Answer (score 5):

I recently bought a book from Amazon titled as ["An Introduction to Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486478831) by Greg Michaelson. It is more of an introduction to functional programming and also introduces lambda calculus. The first impression is quite good. A self contained and easy to read book. [Here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~greg/books/) , you can download free version without index in PostScript.

Answer (score 5):

The book that really made me start to use and understand lambda calculus was "Representation and Inference for Natural Language" by Blackburn and Bos. This is a book about natural language processing using Prolog. Another book you might consider is "Natural Language Understanding" by Allen. Finally, if you like lambda calculus, you will probably also enjoy combinatory logic, as the combinators can be defined as lambda expressions. For this, I strongly recommend Smullyan's book of puzzles, "To Mock A Mockingbird." Toward the end he uses the combinators to build a rudimentary programming language.

Comment: The Blackburn and Bos book is now available online, http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/publikationen/softcopies/Blackburn:1997:RIN.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice explanation (using Scheme): http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2002/Lectures/2002-10-28-lc.pdf

And here's a nifty bit (from my blog), reducing recursive factorial to pure lambdas:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashleyf/archive/2008/12/03/the-lambda-calculus.aspx

Have fun!