# What type of lambda calculus would Lisp loosely be an example of?

Tags: lisp, lambda-calculus, type-theory

I'm trying to get a better grip on how types come into play in lambda calculus.  Admittedly, a lot of the type theory stuff is over my head.  Lisp is a dynamically typed language, would that roughly correspond to untyped lambda calculus?  Or is there some kind of "dynamically typed lambda calculus" that I'm unaware of?

Comment: If we're talking about Lisp, shouldn't it be (lambda (calculus)) ;-)

Comment: As long as you're not talking about Clojure.  Then it would be `(fn [calculus])` :-)

Comment: The problem with this question is that there isn't a single, unique Lisp language, there's a whole family of 'em. To which Lisp(s) are you referring?

Comment: @outis - Any of them.  :-)  Are they really that much different in this regard?

Comment: Common Lisp's type system, with its multimethods and `deftype`, is most likely different from that of the historical LISP (I haven't considered the matter to say to say for sure). Other, uncommon Lisps might have their own peculiarities.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Lisp is a dynamically typed language, would that roughly correspond to untyped lambda calculus?

Yes, but only roughly.  In the "pure" untyped lambda calculus, everything is coded as functions.  (You can google for the popular "Church encoding" and the less popular "Scott encoding".)  Lisp has non-functional data, like atoms and numbers and such, so this would count as "untyped lambda calculus extended with constants."

Another important difference is in **order of evaluation**.  Rules for reducing lambda-calculus terms are highly nondeterministic.  (There's a theorem, the Church-Rosser theorem, which says loosely that as long as things terminate, order of evaluation doesn't matter.)  In practice lambda terms are typically reduced using leftmost-outermost aka "normal-order" reduction because if *any* reduction strategy terminates, that one does.
This is very different from Lisp which always evaluates arguments to normal form before doing a beta-reduction.  This evaluation order is called "call by value."

In summary, Lisp corresponds to **an untyped, call-by-value lambda calculus extended with constants**.

Answer (score 3):

John McCarthy introduced LISP in [his April, 1960 paper "Recursive Functions of Symbolic Expressions and Their Computation by Machine, Part I"](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.pdf). The following paragraph is from page 6:

> e. Functions and Forms. It is usual in mathematics — outside of mathematical logic — to use the word “function” imprecisely and to apply it to forms
>   such as y<sup>2</sup> + x. Because we shall later compute with expressions for functions,
>   we need a distinction between functions and forms and a notation for express-
>   ing this distinction. This distinction and a notation for describing it, from
>   which we deviate trivially, is given by Church [3].
>   
> ...
>   3. A. CHURCH, The Calculi of Lambda-Conversion (Princeton University
>   Press, Princeton, N. J., 1941).

The [Wikipedia article on lambda-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) has a history of Church's publications.  The 1941 paper referenced by McCarthy seems to be about the *typed* lambda-calculus, in contradiction to the Wikipedia article's introduction.

The `lambda` keyword in Lisp can be understood to refer to the lambda-calculus only through analogy.  A Lisp lambda expression is a type of [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Lisp).

Comment: That's what I figured, but I'm trained to think that untyped != dynamically typed.  :-)

Comment: @Heath: however, the quote specifically says that what's taken from the paper is the "distinction between functions and forms and a notiation for expressing this distinction", rather than implementing the system described in the paper.

Answer (score -6):

Lisp is not 'a lambda calculus', I don't know what 'a lambda calculus' is.

If you want to identify lambda calculi by there type system then Lisp is its own of course. The 'lambda' keyword in any lisp before Scheme is certainly pretentious, and after Scheme there's room too to say it is. Just using 'func' would have been more humble. Lisp is a list processor mainly, not a 'lambda calculus'

I also wrote a rather extensive article about this once that attempts to demonstrate why A: the term 'functional programming' is meaningless and B: why the speaking of 'a lambda calculus' rather than 'a type system' is so too:

http://blog.nihilarchitect.net/archives/289/on-functional-programming/

Also, keep in mind that in Lisp, all functions are in effect *single argument* and can only be have *lists* as their arguments.

Comment: your account has been suspended! Thus the link is effectively dead